# SQL Server 2019 External Script Execution Authentication Error on JKS File

Tags: java, sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption, keystore

I'm attempting to put a POC together that leverages the SQL Server 2019 Extensibility Framework & External Languages feature. This enables execution of external languages in SQL Server Stored procedures. I've written a JAR file that encrypts and decrypts data being passed via a SQL Server stored procedure. I've confirmed that the each method is correct, and returns the correct values when not being sent as a stored procedure. However, when executing the stored procedure I receive an empty data set and see the following error in debug mode:

`java.io.FileNotFoundException: <jks-file-location> (Access is denied)`

The line of Java code throwing the error is below:

```
       Key _key = readKeyFromStore_cbs("<jks-file-location>, "<password>".toCharArray(), "entityEncryption", "<password>".toCharArray());
       _keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(_key.getEncoded(), _key.getAlgorithm());
```

Again, the code is fine, I don't think there are issues there, and don't think posting the content of those methods is the issue (the SP itself runs fine with dummy data in the place of data being encrypted and decrypted, and the code with encryption and decryption runs as expected when run on its own).

Additional Info:

- I'm running this on a local Windows 10 environment and have given "Everyone" full security permissions on the jks.
- I've double checked the user running sql server and ensured that user has full permissions on the file as well. (This user also has admin privileges on SQL Server)
- I've checked SQL Server `sp_configure` options as well.
- Filestream is enabled and set to full control in sp_configure
- I've even disabled clr strict security on sp_configure to see if that was the cause. I still receive the same error.
- I've attempted tests with JKS in my User directory (with permissions on the directory and file for the SQL Server user), in the C drive, and in the child directory of the C drive (again, with permissions on the directory and file for the SQL Server user)

The stored procedure runs, but is returning an empty data set. When attempting run without encryption (using the key from the currently inaccessible keystore) and using dummy data, I receive the expected data set.

Anyone know what might be causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Moving the JAR and jks into SQL Server directories and starting the Launchpad service resolved the issue. Hope this helps someone avoid similar frustrations.